# PERL LZW compression with output codes are 9 bits long

Tags: perl, compression, lzw

From the Page : 
http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0072.htm

I am trying use the same details to compress and decompress , it not working any perl modules (LZW)

```
Source ASCII codes : 45 45 45 45 45 65 45 45 45 66

Current Output :  20 1D 00 01 0014 01 01 24

Expected compressed code :80 0B 60 50 22 0C 0C 85 01
```

I want to create a perl script which do LZW compression

code :

```
use strict ;
  use Compress::LZW;

  my $fatdata ='-----A---B';
  my $thindata = $fatdata;

  my $compressed = compress($fatdata);
  $fatdata    = decompress($compressed);

  my $smallcompressed = compress($thindata, 9);
  $thindata        = decompress($smallcompressed, 9);

print $smallcompressed;
```

I have used any other modules , above code is just example. But still i am not getting right output

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  Now can you explain the problem you are having?  What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: problem is the output is not coming as expected . I am expecting 80 0B 60 50 22 0C 0C 85 01  but it shows 20 1D 00 01 14 01 01 24

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Compress%3a%3aLZW) says only `12` and `16` are valid values for the second argument.

Comment: even i use so many other perl modules. even thought its not correct results